# PyMySQL and Pandas return garbled columns for Japanese characters

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, paramiko, pymysql

I am trying to read some tables from a database. When the database contains just numbers and English characters, I get the data OK however my other tables in the database contain some Japanese characters. When I download these tables, the columns with Japanese characters displays all question marks: `???????????`

My code:

```
import pymysql
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder   
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (ssh_host, ssh_port),
        ssh_username=ssh_user,
        ssh_pkey=mypkey,
        remote_bind_address=(sql_ip, sql_port)) as tunnel:
        conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user=sql_username,
                passwd=sql_password, 
                port=tunnel.local_bind_port,db=db,unicode_results=True)

        #data = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
        data = pd.read_sql_query(query_2, conn,)
```

I have tried `pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)` which worked for me previously but it doesn't seem to be helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved my problem and for those interested below is the answer:
I just needed to add `charset='ujis'` to my code.Now it is not garbled.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user=sql_username,
                passwd=sql_password, 
                port=tunnel.local_bind_port,db=db,charset='uji')
```